# Conditional expectation with respect to random closed sets

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Short question**

If $X$ is a random closed set, and $Y$ is an integrable random variable, I would like a definition of the "conditional expectation" $$\mathbf{E}[Y \mid X\ni x].$$  Has this been worked out before? (Please include references.)

[**Update:** *I am looking for definitions that are either (a) axiomatic or (b)a limit/Radon-Nykodym derivative/other construction; in both cases similar to the definition of the standard conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}[Y \mid X=x]$ for a random variable $X$.  (Possibly one may also be able to use known facts about conditional expectation as well.)  I am really hoping that the definition obeys*

1. *$x \mapsto \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X\ni x]$ is $T_X$-capacitable, and*
2. *$\int \mathbf{E}[Y\mid X\ni x]\, d\mathbf{T}_X(x)= \mathbf{E}[Y]$ (where the LHS is a Choquet integral).*

*I don't expect anyone to reinvent this, just to point me in the right direction in the literature.*]

**Long question**

Let $X$ be a random closed set (that is $X$ is a random variable taking values in the space $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{X})$ of closed sets in a (locally compact if needed) Polish space $\mathbb{X}$.).  Let $\mathbf{P}_X$ be the distribution of $X$, that is the associated probability measure on $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{X})$.  Let $\mathbf{T}_X$ be the capacity of $X$, that is $\mathbf{T}_X(A)=\mathbf{P}(A \cap X \neq \varnothing)$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$.  Let $\int f\, d\mathbf{T}_X$ denote the Choquet integral, that is
$$\int f\, d\mathbf{T}_X = \int_0^\infty \mathbf{T}_X\{x : f(x) > t\}\, dt,$$ 
and in the case of random closed sets, we have
$$\int f\, d\mathbf{T}_X = \int \sup_{x\in F} f(x)\,d\mathbf{P}_X(F).$$

Given a random variable $Y$, I would like to define $\mathbf{E}[Y \mid X \ni x]$. Clearly, when $\mathbb{X}$ is discrete this is easy to define.  However, in general I suspect we need to think of the map
$$x \mapsto \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X\ni x]$$
as a $\mathbf{T}_X$-capacitable map (defined quasi-everywhere), and that 
$$\int \mathbf{E}[Y\mid X\ni x]\, d\mathbf{T}_X(x)= \mathbf{E}[Y].$$

While I could take the time to work all this out, I imagine this has been studied and written about in papers and books (which I can't seem to find off hand).

Comment: Try checking out Palm measure. I think this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, I will look more into Palm measures, but at a first glance, they don't seem to be what I want.  They are for point processes/random measures.  Whereas here I am working with random sets.  I don't see the connection...

Comment: Nice question... We can ask question about the function $g(x)=E(Y\mid X=x)$, defined by $g(X)=E(Y\mid X)$, as long as they don't distinguish $g$ from another function $h$ where $g(x)=h(x)$ for almost all $x$. But in this case if $g(C)=E(Y\mid X=C)$ then for each particular $x$, $\{C\in x\}$ is a particular measure zero sets of $C$'s and therefore forbidden...

Comment: Perhaps "Graf, S. (1980). A Radon-Nikodym theorem for capacities. J. Reine Angew. Math. 320, 192–214." might be a good launching off point.

Comment: Or "Hess, C. (1999). Conditional expectation and martingales of random sets. Pattern Recognition 32, 1543–1567."